# MOTD debian - is this ever changed by an update?

Tags: debian

Is this ever changed automatically by a system update?

I'm just wondering as I set a 'hilarious' one for a personal server off rackspace cloud, and it seems to have been deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See /etc/init.d/bootlogs

Specifically this line

```
# Update motd
uname -snrvm > /var/run/motd
[ -f /etc/motd.tail ] && cat /etc/motd.tail >> /var/run/motd
```

Meaning you should put your changes to motd in /etc/motd.tail otherwise its going to get overwritten on boot.

Answer (score 1):

It might be interesting to add that editing `/etc/motd.tail` is not enough, the above snippet must be executed to update `/etc/motd`, the system only updates it on reboot (well, how often do you reboot your servers?)

Just out of lazyness, and because my server has no load anyways, I update `/etc/motd` every minute by using cron to execute exactly the code mentioned above.